# spring data jpa isolation

Tags: oracle, spring-data-jpa, spring-transactions

I use spring boot with spring data jpa with hibernate and oracle

I need to take data of a datable with a couple of millions of record and write data in a file. After data it's wrote, I need to remove the row.
I thing using stream to get data.

During theses process, some of other data can be inserted in the table (by another program).

Don't know if when we stream database, new insertion are added to the query.

I was thinking doing somehting like

```
public void processData(){

  //create file    

  Stream<Billing> billingStream = billingRepository.getAll();

  billingStream.forEach( billing-> {

    //write billing row to file

    //delete billing row; //should be remove in memory
    entityManager.remove(billing);

  });

}
```

If inserted, is there a way to avoid to take it?

Comment: The stream API only retrieves the list of all elements. and its convert the retrieved list into a stream.

Comment: I think you can avoid all of this using pagination, it will be better for retrieval elements, and with better performance if matter.

Comment: that depend of the implementation, seem like hibernate use scroll